# How to run the job within springbatchadmin.war from the command line?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

How to run the job within springbatchadmin.war from command line?

I used the following command in command prompt to run the job.

```
D:\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\webapps\springbatchadmin>java -classpath "lib\*;src" com.companyname.batch.BatchLauncher job1Cfg job1
```

But I got the error and I cannot run the job.

Please give me right directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using tomcat for deploying the admin, then the .war file should have deployed itself into a folder as soon as you start the server once. Now you can trace to the location of the xml files inside that folder, and execute jobs from command-line.

eg: in my case, the xml files are in the folder,

> tomcat\webapps\my_project_war\WEB-INF\classes\springbatch

So just in case you want to run a job (say `'abcJob'`) inside an xml, say `'xyz.xml'`,

use the command,

```
java org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner "tomcat\webapps\my_project_war\WEB-INF\classes\springbatch\xyz.xml" "abcJob" parameter1=value1 etc
```

While running from command-line, you can also set the classpath variable to some constant location, so that you can run all relative jobs with reference to that location. (in my case it is'tomcat\webapps\my_project_war\WEB-INF\classes')

So I would use the command,

```
java org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner "classpath*:springbatch/xyz.xml" "abcJob" parameter1=value1
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error "Error: Could not find or load main class CommandLineJobRunner"